# How to convert radians to degrees

Tags: java, trigonometry

I'm making a trig calculator to practice aviation problems for fun and can't convert radians to degrees properly in java.

I've tried taking altitude divided by Math.tan(angle) and times it by (180 / Math.PI) but this doesn't give me the answer I'm looking for. 
The numbers I've tried include alt = 500, angle of approach = 3. My code will store these values and take 500/tan(3) * (180/Pi) and I'm unsure why this isn't the correct trigonometry behind it.

```
     public static void approachPath() {
       System.out.println("FINDING THE IDEAL APPROACH PATH . . . ");
       System.out.println("What is the altitude of the aircraft:");
       double alt = scan.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("What is the angle of approach:");
       double angleofapproach = scan.nextDouble();

       //line my problem occurs on
       double approachPath = (alt / Math.tan(angleofapproach)) * (180 / Math.PI);

       System.out.println("The ideal approach path is: " + approachPath);
    }
```

I'm expecting the answer 9,541feet so I can move on to writing the rest of the method to find the final approach path in nautical miles.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Math function, `Math.toDegrees`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right. Just instead of rad to deg, it should be deg to rad.

```
double angleofapproach = toRad(scan.nextDouble());
double approachPath = (alt / Math.tan(angleofapproach));

// deg to rad
public static double toRad(double deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}
```